# Importing data from Excel into SQL Server using VB.Net and Dataset or Datatable

Tags: sql-server, excel, vb.net, datatable, dataset

I am trying to import data from Excel into SQL Server. Though this topic has been discussed numerous times, but my question is a bit different. My requirement is as follows:

1. Fetch data from Excel and load into a DataTable / DataSet, [**I am able to do that**]
2. Do validation operations on the imported data. There are a few columns that have text data and need to be replaced with Numeric data e.g. Currency Name is imported from Excel and replaced with Currency ID etc. I have already imported from SQL Server the Currency table into Dataset. So I need to know how to query one table in Dataset while fetching information from another table in same Dataset. [**I need help here**]
3. Create a new DataTable using few columns from Imported Data and other columns that were fetched by code e.g. Currency ID to replace Currency Name etc [**I need help here**]
4. Save this date into SQL Server using Dataset. [**I need help here**]

Excel Sheet Columns - **Stored in Dataset**

```
   CURRENCY   CUSTOMER NAME     PACKING TYPE    WEIGHT  ZONE    PRICE
   ------------------------------------------------------------------- 
    GBP         STANDARD        FEDEX ENVELOPE  0.25    A       20 
    GBP         STANDARD        FEDEX ENVELOPE  0.25    B       28 
    USD         STANDARD        FEDEX BOX       0.25    C       29
```

Currency Table Fields (SQL Server) **stored in Dataset**

```
Currency_ID Currency_Code
1               GBP
2               USD
```

Packing Table Fields (SQL Server) **stored in Dataset**

```
PackID    PackName
1         FEDEX ENVELOPE
2         FEDEX BOX
```

Final Data to be imported into SQL Server.

```
   CURRENCY   CUSTOMER NAME     PACKING TYPE    WEIGHT  ZONE    PRICE
   ------------------------------------------------------------------- 
    1           STANDARD           1             0.25   A       20 
    1           STANDARD           1             0.25   B       28 
    2           STANDARD           2             0.25   C       29
```

I am able to import the data from Excel into Dataset. Now I need way to export the data into SQL Server using the same Dataset while editing the data i.e. Replacing some text columns with ID

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: It looks like you already have all the pieces. Use the `DataTable.Select()` method to filter a value. Loop the Rows of the Excel DataTable, extract and convert the values (e.g., `dim currencyCode = [CurrencyTable].Select($"Currency_Code = {excelRow(0)}).FirstOrDefault()?("Currency_ID") dim packID = [PackingTable].Select($"PackName = {excelRow(2)}).FirstOrDefault()?("PackID")`), convert `currencyCode` and `packID` to `Int32`, `ExcelRow(3)` and `ExcelRow(5)` to `Decimal`, add a Row, using these values, to the SQLServer DataTable, then call `[DataSet].AcceptChanges()` and `[DataAdapter].Update()`

Comment: @Jimi `AcceptChanges` marks everything unmodified and will prevent database updates.

Comment: @Crowcoder  Yes, well, I had a fight with the comment editor because of its max length limitation. It won. Some cuts are not that *precise*. I assume the OP knows that you don't call AcceptChanges if you also use a DataAdapter. There's another cut that makes *add a Row, (...) to the SQLServer DataTable* sound weird, but I assume the OP knows which Row of which DataTable I'm referring to. All in all, good enough to trigger a response comment (which would make it clear if this question is a *write this code for me* type or *I have a problem with this specific thing* type).

Comment: Thanks @Crowcoder  for your comments. Let me try and revert.